# Getting 401 unauthorized error while accessing webDav folder from my C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, debian, webdav

I have set up WebDAv server on my Debian linux and this is working fine as I am able to connect it by using FireFox and IE.

But while I am trying to connect it by the following code, it returns:

```
"The remote server returned and error:(401) Unauthorized error"
```

---

```
try
{
                // Build the SQL query.
                strQuery = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><D:searchrequest xmlns:D = \"DAV:\" >";
                strQuery += "<D:sql>SELECT \"DAV:href\" FROM scope('hierarchical traversal of \"";
                strQuery += strRootURI + "\"')</D:sql></D:searchrequest>";

                // Create a new CredentialCache object and fill it with the network
                // credentials required to access the server.
                MyCredentialCache = new System.Net.CredentialCache();
                MyCredentialCache.Add(new System.Uri(strRootURI),
                   "NTLM",
                   new System.Net.NetworkCredential(strUserName, strPassword)
                   );

                // Create the HttpWebRequest object.
                Request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(strRootURI);

                // Add the network credentials to the request.
                Request.Credentials = MyCredentialCache;

                // Specify the method.
                Request.Method = "SEARCH";

                // Encode the body using UTF-8.
                bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)strQuery);

                // Set the content header length.  This must be
                // done before writing data to the request stream.
                Request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

                // Get a reference to the request stream.
                RequestStream = Request.GetRequestStream();

                // Write the SQL query to the request stream.
                RequestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                // Close the Stream object to release the connection
                // for further use.
                RequestStream.Close();

                // Set the content type header.
                Request.ContentType = "text/xml";

                // Send the SEARCH method request and get the
                // response from the server.
                Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();

                // Get the XML response stream.
                ResponseStream = Response.GetResponseStream();

                // Create the XmlTextReader object from the XML
                // response stream.
                XmlReader = new XmlTextReader(ResponseStream);

                // Read through the XML response, node by node.
                while (XmlReader.Read())
                {
                    // Look for the opening DAV:href node.  The DAV: namespace is
                    //typically assigned the a: prefix in the XML response body.
                    if (XmlReader.Name == "a:href")
                    {
                        // Advance the reader to the text node.
                        XmlReader.Read();

                        // Display the value of the DAV:href text node.
                        Console.WriteLine("Value: " + XmlReader.Value);
                        Console.WriteLine("");

                        //Advance the reader to the closing DAV:href node.
                        XmlReader.Read();
                    }
                }

                // Clean up.
                XmlReader.Close();
                ResponseStream.Close();
                Response.Close();

            }
```

I am unable to understand why the anuathorized error is happening while the same credentials are working throgh web browser. There are domains so I left the Domain field as blank.

Is this the Authentication type `NLTM` or something else. Please help .

Thanks,

Subhen

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answered at the following Post :

[Sample code for WebDAV PROPFIND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137995/sample-code-for-profind/3148449#3148449)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137995/sample-code-for-profind/3148449#3148449 does not mention 401.