# Sample code for WebDAV PROPFIND

Tags: webdav

Is there any site or some one can provide me a sample PROFIND request please.

I tried the PROFIND code sample from MSDN but getting 400 Bad request.

Unable to understand why this is happening.

Previously posted the question at [Getting 400 Bad request from WebDav Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132746/getting-400-bad-request-from-webdav-server)

Any suggestions will be greatly helpfull.

**Edit**

@Julian,

Have updated my request body to the following:

```
 strBody = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"
                 + "<propfind xmlns='DAV:'>"
                 + "<allprop/>"
                + "</propfind>";
```

as explained at [RFC 4918, Section 9.1](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#rfc.section.9.1)

But I am still getting the 400 Bad request Error. M I missing any Headers . Please suggest  I am setting the following Header Information:

```
 System.Net.HttpWebRequest Request;
 Request.Credentials = MyCredentialCache;
 Request.Method = "PROPFIND";

 bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)strBody);
 Request.ContentType = "text/xml";
```

Do I need to set or specify something additional. The full code is in my [Previosu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132746/getting-400-bad-request-from-webdav-server) Question.

Thanks,

Subhen

Comment: Asking the same question again isn't really helpful. RFC 4918 has examples; did you try them?

Comment: @Julian, Tried with RFC 4918, Section 9.1 and still getting the 400 error. Updated the Post.
Thanks

Comment: Did you check what the response body says?

Comment: I am getting the exception when I reach at Response i.e: Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse(); in the code

Comment: Check the request/response *bodies*, for instance, with http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I was missing the Depth Header and for that reason the webserver was returning Method Not allowed error.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa142960(v=EXCHG.65).aspx) clearlystates that
*A PROPFIND with depth value of "infinity" is not supported in the public store that is accessible to MAPI clients such as Microsoft Outlook.*

And the Bad request 404 error was generated because I was not using proxy. So What I did I commented the line which was not using any proxy and added the Depth Header.

```
 // Request.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();
Request.Headers.Add("Depth", "1");
```